# How can I retrieve entity relationships with limitations using Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is an optimization question regarding relationships and db round-trips.

**TL;DR:** You have two entities, A and B, with a many-to-many relationship. You need to retrieve an instance of A along with a specific *subset* of its related B entities. **This is the important part**, you do not want to retrieve all B entities related to that A instance, only a subset of them.

**Long Story**

Consider following entities;

```java
public class A {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany
  private List<B> bList;
}
```

```java
public class B {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany
  private List<A> aList;

  private Boolean somePropertyToUseWhileFiltering;
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve an instance of A entity, along with a subset of its related B instances. The way I see it, this can be achieved three ways;

1. Get all the related B entities while retrieving A, and discard the unwanted ones.
2. Make two different repository calls with a lazy relationship: First get the A instance without the related B instances, then get the B instances specifying the desired filters and limitations.
3. Write a huge-ass custom JPQL or SQL query that will get the A instance and the specific subset of related B instances.

I don't like the first approach at all because it will retrieve a lot of unnecessary rows. The third approach might be the best approach for complex structures, but then why the hell am I using an ORM structure in the first place?

In theory all of these should work, and I'm currently using the second approach, but I have a concern. Is making multiple repository calls to different repositories bad for a single request? Because I have a complex entity structure with so many relations. I'm guessing it will increase the round-trips to the database.

Is there any other, more suitable approach to this problem?

Comment: ORM is a swiss army knife that give you shortcuts for some stuff, not a magic trick to do all stuff easly, indeed it has some limits. 2nd and 3rd approach is the same, imho; " huge-ass custom" inquiry will be the same, seems change just the repository in wich is written

Comment: maybe you're right, guess I'm expecting too much from these utilities. still think it would be very useful to have this kind of feature though.

are you sure about 2nd and 3rd approaches being the same? because with the second approach, I'm seeing multiple hibernate query logs in my console. doesn't this mean the app is making multiple round-trips to the database?

Comment: thinking better, the 2nd and 3rd approaches are not the same thing. As you could see the 2nd way suffers from the "N+1 select problem" (1 select for A entities and N select for B entities where N is the number of A entities retrieved). As always, it depends on a case by case, but in broad terms, I would be inclined to favor the third way if you expecting huge data-set

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use nested projection:
projection

```
public interface AWithFilteredBListProjection {

    Long getId();

    List<BProjection> getFilteredBList();

    interface BProjection {
        String getSomePropertyToUseWhileFiltering();

        // Add other properties from B that you want to include
    }
}
```

repository

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.bList b WHERE a.id = :aId")
    Optional<AWithFilteredBListProjection> findAWithFilteredBList(@Param("aId") Long aId);
}
```

Comment: but where exactly is the filtering in this? I need something like "A entity with its B relations where somePropertyToUseWhileFiltering is true (or sometimes false)". sorry if that wasn't clear enough in the question.

Comment: you mean like this?:    ``` interface BProjection {
        String getSomePropertyToUseWhileFiltering();
       Boolean getInvalid();
        // Add other properties from B that you want to include
    }```    **************************                                                                                                  ``` @Query("SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.bList b WHERE a.id = :aId AND b.invalid= :invalid")
    Optional<AWithFilteredBListProjection> findAWithFilteredBList(@Param("aId") Long aId,@Param("invalid") Boolean invalid);```

Comment: yeah something like that, I'll probably go with the @Query approach.